# How to get TLS version and applicable cipher suits from Http Request

Tags: java, ssl, twilio

I am using Twilio sandbox environment for testing WhatsApp integration with my application. As I moved application to different server twilio API is sending **Error 20426 Upgrade Required**.

Application was working fine on previous server. TLS version on both the server is 1.2 and SSL version is 3. Cipher Suits are also present on both servers as List provided in Twilio document. The only difference between two servers is the OS. On server where application is working OS installed is Linux and where application is not working OS is AIX 7.

Comment: That error suggests that you do not have TLS v1.2 available on the AIX 7 server. Have you tried making a request over TLS to the server yourself and inspecting the response?

Comment: I have checked the TLS version on the server.Enabled version is 1.2.Can you please explain how can make a TLS request to the server.

Comment: Make an https request using something like curl or postman and inspect the response.

Comment: Maybe you are using Tomcat without Tomcat-native+apr+OpenSSL.

Comment: @philnash I tried inspecting response but not able to find anything related to TLS.

Comment: @CharanjitRana When I make a verbose curl request to my server [it looks like this](https://monosnap.com/direct/DjL6LHqEsIbpL9zlKifLtUrHxg1rp8). If you're not seeing something like that, then your TLS is not set up correctly. Have you checked Lorinczy Zsigmond's suggestion?

Comment: @Lorinczy Zsigmond I am using Jboss Server and Open SSl